# Update Transients instead of insert new Transients in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How to update transient instead of insert new transient in wordpress?

Because After expiration Must be cleared Transients.

Answer (score 0):

For this need to save date of end in transient value.

Example:

```
//on create
$expiration = 60*60*12;
$time_to_end = time() + $expiration;
set_transient( 
  'transient_name', 
  array('value'=>'some_data', 'end_time'=>$time_to_end), 
  $expiration 
);

//for update
$previous = get_transient( 'transient_name');
$expiration = $previous['end_time'] -  time();
if ( $expiration > 0 ){
set_transient( 
  'transient_name', 
  array('value'=>'some_new_data', 'end_time'=>$previous['end_time'] ),
  $expiration
);
}
```